# Preprocessed block not udpating after edit

Tags: 8, caching

I am preprocessing a block which seems to get cache and not showing the updated content on front end after getting edit.

My preprocess code looks like:-

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
 */
function mymodule_aboutus_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $act_on_blocks = array(
    'myblockid',
  );
  if (!in_array($variables['elements']['#id'], $act_on_blocks)) {
    return;
  }
  $block = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
  $body = $variables['content']['body'];
  switch ($variables['elements']['#id']) {
    case 'myblockid':
      $variables['myblock_data']['field_title'] = t('Credits');
      $variables['myblock_data']['field_description'] = $body;
      break;
  }
}

- On Twig template
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    {% include "@mytheme/myblock-partial" with {
      "title": myblock_data['field_title'],
      "content": myblock_data['field_description'],
    } only %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drupal 8 caching background in breif:-**

Drupal 8 has **strong** and awesome caching mechanism.

Basically any renderable array is now get cached by default and drupal provides cache API to manage in what context
(could be in context of user/route etc.)(cache contetx), when to invalidate the cache(cache tags) and till when it should
be cached could be Permanent cache(max-age=-1) or no caching at all(max-age=0)

So the renderable array Cache API works around

1. Cache Context
2. Cache Tags
3. max-age

The problem with my code was excessive preprocessing on block content and then avoid `{{ content }}` to print on block 
twig template, so `{{ content }}` itself take care of `'#cache'` attribute but since I avoided it during preprocessing 
and printed only my custom exposed variables drupal was never able to figure out when to invalidate the cache, and 
blocks were permanent cached.

Solution:
I just made sure I am also passing the '#cache' attribute to my renderable arrays and then used the same on twig template

```
  // - Example during preprocessing

    /**
     * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
     */
    function cfr_world_aboutus_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
      $act_on_blocks = array(
        'myblockid',
      );
      if (!in_array($variables['elements']['#id'], $act_on_blocks)) {
        return;
      }
      $block = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
      $body = $variables['content']['body'];
      switch ($variables['elements']['#id']) {
        case 'myblockid':
          $variables['myblock_data']['field_title'] = t('Credits');
          $variables['myblock_data']['field_description'] = $body;
          // Added drupal cache attribute
          $variables['myblock_data']['#cache'] = $variables['elements']['content']['#cache'];
          break;
      }
    }

    // - On Twig template
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
      {{ title_prefix }}
      {% if label %}
        <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
      {% endif %}
      {{ title_suffix }}
      {% block content %}
        {# Added to pass cache attribute#}
        {{ myblock_data| without('field_title','field_description') }}
        {% include "@mytheme/myblock-partial" with {
          "title": myblock_data['field_title'],
          "content": myblock_data['field_description'],
        } only %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
```